# How are the @Value at the constructor really useful?

Tags: java

I have this doubt....

I was trying to have a default value for a field in my object, default value I wanted to bring it from a properties.

So, I thought about use it this way

```
@Value("${app.message.text:default}")
final String text;

final Object object

MyClass(Object object){
   this.object = object;
}


//getters for both fields
```

Well, text is always null....

Then I tried this way

```
final String text;
final Object object

MyClass(Object object, @Value("${app.message.text:default}") final String text){
   this.object = object;
   this.text = text
}
```

It does work, but then at the constructors I have to specify the value of text.... then I will never use the default from the property... Did I misunderstand this? is there anyway to archive what I am trying using this @Value?

Thanks.

Comment: `@Value` only applies to Spring-managed beans. If your class is not managed by Spring, it won't get a chance to do anything, which is why your `@Value` field is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The reason why it won't work at property level:*

When you annotate a class member, Spring uses reflection to set the value (after object is created). Now, in this case, the field is marked as final so it has to be set while creating an object (and not *after* the object is created) so the only way to `@Value` final fields would be to use constructor injection.

*The reason why it doesn't work in constructor:*

Spring only sets the value using `@Value` if the bean is created via Spring (i.e. by `@Component`, `@Configuration` or `@Bean` annotation so make sure your class is annotated with either of these.